# Proof Depending on the Law of Excluded Middle

Tags: logic, axioms

I have just embarked on a journey in logic. Currently I am getting acquainted with axiom schemas and formal proofs. In the process of constructing such a (formal) proof, I have used the Law of Excluded Middle (LoEM), and found myself asking two questions:

1. Can I proof the statement without LoEM?
2. More generally, is it possible to characterize (in some appropriate sense) the set of statements provable without LoEM?

Concretely, I am working with the following axiom schemas:
\begin{align}
  &\text{LoEM}\colon \varphi \lor \lnot\varphi\\
  &\text{L}_1\colon \varphi \to (\psi \to \varphi)\\
  &\text{L}_2\colon (\psi \to (\varphi_1 \to \varphi_2)) \to ((\psi \to \varphi_1) \to (\psi \to \varphi_2))\\
  &\text{L}_3\colon (\varphi \land \psi) \to \varphi\\
  &\text{L}_4\colon (\varphi \land \psi) \to \psi\\
  &\text{L}_5\colon \varphi \to (\psi \to (\varphi \land \psi))\\
  &\text{L}_6\colon \varphi \to (\varphi \lor \psi)\\
  &\text{L}_7\colon \psi \to (\varphi \lor \psi)\\
  &\text{L}_8\colon (\varphi_1 \to \varphi_3) \to ((\varphi_2 \to \varphi_3) \to ((\varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2) \to \varphi_3))\\
  &\text{L}_9\colon \lnot\varphi \to (\varphi \to \psi)
\end{align}

I wish to produce a formal proof of the statement $(\alpha \to (\beta \land \lnot\beta)) \to \lnot\alpha$. (A formal proof is a finite sequence of statements, where each statement is derived from its predecessors or from the axiom schemas above via modus ponens.) To produce a formal proof on the basis of LoEM, note that by $\text{L}_1$,
\begin{equation}
  \lnot\alpha \to ((\alpha \to (\beta \land \lnot\beta)) \to \lnot\alpha).
\end{equation}
It is also not too difficult to show (via *ex falso quodlibet*) that
\begin{equation}
  \alpha \to ((\alpha \to (\beta \land \lnot\beta)) \to \lnot\alpha).
\end{equation}
The desired statement then follows from $\text{L}_8$ and, crucially, LoEM (because $\alpha \lor \lnot\alpha$). My first question, now stated precisely, is whether we can prove $(\alpha \to (\beta \land \lnot\beta)) \to \lnot\alpha$ without LoEM? My intuition tells me that this is not possible, because $\text{L}_1$ - $\text{L}_9$ differ fundamentally from LoEM in that the the former represent inference rules, not assumptions - and our proof has to start with at least one such.

My dilemma is that I don't see a way of formalizing this intuition. This naturally leads to the second question, which asks for a (formally verifiable?) criterion to determine if LoEM is required for the proof of a statement.

Many thanks in advance for your interest and help!

Comment: See Intuitionistic Logic for a system that rejects LEM.

Comment: You have listed your axioms (thank you for doing this!), but you haven't said what your inference rules are. Do you just have Modus Ponens? You say "via *ex falso quodlibet*" - do you have another inference rule that corresponds to ex falso?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I am aware of the motivation behind Intuitionistic Logic (and that it essentially corresponds to $\text{L}_1$ - $\text{L}_9$), but fail to find any resources that address my question. Perhaps you could point me to some?

Regarding Alex's question: Please excuse the lack of precision - indeed, I only want to rely on modus ponens, but for simplicity, let's add $\text{L}_{10}\colon \varphi \land \lnot\varphi \to \psi$ to the list of axiom schemas.

Comment: The "standard" approach is to use semantics. IL is sound and complete for e.g. Kripke's semantics: this means that LEM is not *valid*. Thus, the approach to underivability is to show that a certain formula $\varphi$ is not valid.

Comment: Regarding  $(α→(β∧¬β))→¬α$ (Negation Introduction), it is intuitionisticaly valid  and thus it must be provable.